# how can i write for statement this way : for i not in x

Tags: python, nltk

for words classification, i defined positive and negatives vocabularies, and
i want to identify neutral words (there are an infinity of neutral words)

so I did this :

```
def word_feats(word): 
return {word: True}   
voc_pos = [ 'beauty', 'good', 'happy']    
voc_neg = [ 'bad', 'sick','lazy']    
voc = voc_pos + voc_neg    
pos_feats = [(word_feats(pos), 'pos') for pos in voc_pos]     
neg_feats = [(word_feats(neg), 'neg')for neg in voc_neg]    
neu_feats = [(word_feats(neu), 'neu')for neu not in voc]
```

the error is :

```
"invalid syntax" for neu_feats = [(word_feats(neu), 'neu')for neu not in voc]
```

Comment: `neu not in voc` is what you need to look for!

Comment: [( {'beauty':True}, 'pos'), ( {'book':True}, 'neu'), ( {'bad':True}, 'neg')]

Comment: There is no `book` in there.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need the list of neutral words and why they are structured in a list of tuples instead of a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from @blue_note's answer:

Using [`zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
def word_feats(word):
        return {word: True}

voc_pos = [ 'beauty', 'good', 'happy']
voc_neg = [ 'bad', 'sick','lazy']
voc = voc_pos + voc_neg

mylist = ['book']

pos_feats = [(word_feats(pos), 'pos') for pos in voc_pos]
neu_feats = [(word_feats(neu), 'neu') for neu in mylist if neu not in voc]
neg_feats = [(word_feats(neg), 'neg') for neg in voc_neg]

print([*zip_longest(pos_feats, neu_feats, neg_feats)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[(({'beauty': True}, 'pos'), ({'book': True}, 'neu'), ({'bad': True}, 'neg')), (({'good': True}, 'pos'), None, ({'sick': True}, 'neg')), (({'happy': True}, 'pos'), None, ({'lazy': True}, 'neg'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not valid:

```
for neu not in voc:
```

The reason why is that the list that that could would produce is infinite!
As blue_note says, you can check two lists against each other. You could also do it with collections instead of lists:

```
for neu in all_words - set(voc_pos) - set(voc_neg):
```

Where all_words is some other collection that you have made

Comment: it works, but what i need is to define my train set like this : train = pos_feats +neg_feats + neu_feats and all_words will be the test series

Answer (score 0):

`for` works with `in`. `not in` **is not** a conjuction of `not` and `in`. It is a separate operator.

So, use list comprehension

```
[(word_feats(neu), 'neu') for neu in mylist if neu not in voc]
```

Comment: it works, but what i need is to define my train set like this : train = pos_feats +neg_feats  + neu_feats and mylist will be the test series

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over anything not in a list, because that would be an infinite(and undefined) set.

If you define your domain, for example all integers from 1 to 10, then you can iterate over the items not in a list lst like so:

```
domain = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst = [1,2,3]
# what you want:
neu = [(word_feats(neu), 'neu')for neu in (set(domain)-set(lst))]
```

However, I think you need to tackle this differently. Since you're unlikely to have a list of all words in existence to instantiate this list, and such a list would be difficult to work with, perhaps it would be easier to check if a word is neutral by checking if its neither in `pos_feats` nor in `neg_feats`?

Comment: it works, but what i need is to define my train set like this : train = pos_feats +neg_feats + neu_feats and domain will be the test series

Comment: In that case, load the test set as well, define `domain=set(test_set) + set(train_set)`, and then you can use the method in my answer: `neu = [(word_feats(neu), 'neu') for neu in (domain-set(neg_feats)-set(pos_feats))]`